# PHP CGI and FPM, what are they?

Tags: php, cgi, fpm

I'dlike to ask you (as a newbie) what are these two guys. I found out that they are modes of PHP to run on server, is that correct? Whats more to that? Every topic seems to be like , what's faster better, but I'd like to know what are they in first place...

Comment: Basically correct, they are different alternatives, as always there is no "better", only different. I suggest you read the documentation.

Comment: FPM is a PHP implementation which can run on the [FastCGI protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI).  The more you get into these things the longer the explanations get, so you probably should just enter the google/wikipedia rabbit hole on this topic as it's too long to be answered in SO.

Comment: In CGI (which was the original, slower method), the web server creates a whole new process for each request. In FPM, the serving process stays running and the web server just passes the request to it via a socket so the time taken is just the time to create a socket - which is less than the time to create a process.